# How do I get the latest version of AUDACITY to convert from WAV to MP3?

Tags: updates, audacity

Would like to convert my audio files in WAV format to MP3 format. I learned that this can be done with AUDACITY. But, using AUDACITY 2.1.2 I could not get the response that the instructions said I should.

If there is a better way to convert from WAV to MP3 I'd be glad to try.

Comment: Audacity has been able to convert from WAV to mp3 since time immemorial. The current version in the repos is 2.2.2-1.

Comment: Seems like a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You seem want to convert audio files, and there are many ways to do that without Audacity. But instead you are asking about how to implement your chosen (complex, difficult) course of action.

Comment: Title doesn't match the body. Please [edit] to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Sound Converter (*soundconverter*) from the default Ubuntu repositories is much better than Audacity for converting wav to mp3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound Converter from the default Ubuntu repositories is much better than Audacity for converting wav to mp3. To install Sound Converter in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install soundconverter
```

Comment: It worked!! Your terminal commands were most important. Could not have found soundconverter otherwise.